# FOSS solution for a local machine: DNS

Tags: macos, dns

I love my Mac. But I have always found that my DNS lookups are as slow, even while flushing caches and I travel over known roads on the Internet (I frequently visit the same websites over and over again). I was wondering if someone would know something a bit more automatic/intelligent than /etc/hosts and less complex and iron forged as BIND.

Thank you for your feedback and answers!

Comment: You travel "know roads" and you want what?

Comment: No, because this is something that doesn't affect a bunch of networking computers (which would have a proxy and dns solution if done right), but a laptop that could perform better by a workaround :) If it would be a howto question about BIND for 20 boxes, then it would belong to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run [pdnsd](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~rombouts/pdnsd.html) on my laptop, it has the option to permanently cache dns addresses in case of an unavailable dns server and it can use multiple dns server parallel so you always get a fast response. The timeout is completely configurable so you'll never have to wait long if you don't want to :)

Comment: It looks awesome. The website noted it has some notes regarding BSD-like environments (Darwin is BSD). So, I am going to grind through the docs and sources. Thank you!